# strange class error on the main form

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

well i got this and i'm not sure how to resolve it

Warning 1   The class Form1 can be designed, but is not the first class in the file.  Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file.  Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file and try loading the designer again.     0   0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably declared another class in your Form1.cs file. That class should be moved to its own file.

For example, this is bad:

```
using ...

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Foobar
    {
        ...
    }
    public partial class Form1
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this example, `Foobar` should be moved to a file called Foobar.cs.

Comment: thanks for explaining it indeed i was doing that, with a few undo i got back to my old situation again pfww..

Answer (score 0):

You have another class declared above the Form1 class in your Form1.cs. Move the Form1 class above it...